# Batch script to set a variable from text file not working

Tags: batch-file

I am having an issue with setting a variable from a text file in a batch script.
There is only one line in the text file and it is `testabc`.

The script is

```
set /p p_password=<c:\temp\passport.txt
echo %p_password%
```

The echo statement should have `testabc`, but it is actually having the below `■t`.

I even tried it with a `for` loop

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (c:\temp\passport.txt) do set p_password=%%a
echo %p_password%
```

I still get the same output; `■t`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible the text file is saved as UTF-8 with a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm that using different a file encoding format will fix this problem.

Using the input text file mentioned in your question, and saving the text file using `UltraEdit`, the results are listed below for the different encoding formats:

- ANSI/ASCII = `testabc`
- UTF-8 = `∩╗┐testabc`
- UTF-16 =  `■t`
- UTF-8 - NO BOM = `testabc`
- UTF-16 - NO BOM = `t`
- UTF-16 - Big Endian = `■`
- UTF-16 - Big Endian - NO BOM = *(empty string)*
- Unicode - ASCII Escaped = `testabc`

As mentioned earlier by the commentor, it seems your text file was saved with a [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).